# How to deploy AWS-Lambda with boto3 and Docker?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, boto3

**Environment**.
jupyterlab, python 3.8.
ubuntu 20.04LTS.
(Client : macos bigsur / google chrome).
using boto3.

**Situation**.
I builded docker image and pushed it to ECR successfully.
That image has awslambdaric and contains aws-lambda-rie.
I can deploy that image with AWS Lambda console.

**I want**.
Deploy it to lambda using boto3(=python code).

**problem**.
Following boto3 manual, deploying lambda is like next:

```
import boto3
lambdac = boto3.client('lambda')
dic = {
    'FunctionName':'lambda-name',
#    'Runtime':'python3.8',
    'Role':'my-role-arn',
    'Code':{'ImageUri':uri},
}
lambdac.create_function(**dic)
```

This make error.
It needs Runtime, so I added runtime (I think docker container version doesn't need runtime).
And run, and another error returns.

```
InvalidParameterValueException: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Runtime and Handler are mandatory parameters for functions created with deployment packages.
```

The error makes me think "Isn't support boto3 deploy lambda with container?"
Because I didn't saw a example deploying container to lambda with boto3.

**Question**.
Is not boto3 supply deploying container to lambda?
Or Other boto3 function supplies it? (ecr client or others...).
Or is there any other method for python developing environment to deploy a container to lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it myself.

the kwargs of create_function needs "PackageType":"Image"

```
import boto3
lambdac = boto3.client('lambda')
dic = {
    'FunctionName':'lambda-name',
    'Role':'my-role-arn',
    'Code':{'ImageUri':uri},
    'PackageType':'Image'   #add this parameter
}
lambdac.create_function(**dic)
```